# accessing speicific array elements with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

If my PHP returns a array with 6 elements how would I access each of them specifically in jquery?

For example I want to create:

var itemOne = value of first array element;
var itemTwo = value of second array element;
...

```
$.get('ajax/employee_menu.php', { job: $('#job').val() },      
        function(data) 
        {
            //i want to put each value from 'data' into variables here.
         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have a javascript array, you can access array indexes in the same way as you would in PHP:

```
var itemOne = arrayFromPHP[0];
var itemTwo = arrayFromPHP[1];
```

If you don't have a javascript array, you could use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to convert a PHP array to javascript:

```
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
var itemOne = arrayFromPHP[0];
```

or you could make an AJAX request (example using jQuery):

PHP:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(
    array( 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' )
);
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var itemOne = data[0];
});
```

Comment: The array would be returned from a .get